# assembly language registers

Tags: assembly

I was learning assembly programming and I encountered some issues with registries. For example i came across this:

```
mov ax, 3000
mov ds, ax
mov si, 200
mov ax, [si]
add si, 2
add ax, [si]
add si, 2
mov [si], ax
mov ax, 4c00
int 21
```

this code makes the sum of 2 memory segments from 3000:200 and 3000:202 and put's the result on 3000:202 and I don't understand the connection between ds and si because I can't explain why we do mov ds , ax ? and I generally don't understand the connection between registers... I know what they stand for but... I don't know some help would be very useful thanks

Answer (score 4):

DS is the data segment register - like all segment registers, its value multiplied by 16 represents the base address of a 64K chunk of memory.

When executing instructions, memory addresses are calculated by taking the base address represented by a segment register (by default, the DS register is used for data) and adding an offset value specified by a constant or a register.

So, `mov ax, [si]` is equivalent to `mov ax, [ds:si]` which (with your register values) represents `mov ax, [3000:200]`. Internally, the processor will calculate the absolute memory address of (3000*16)+200 and copy the data from that memory location into `ax`. A similar procedure is used for the memory accesses when adding and saving the result.

The reason you can't do `mov ds, 3000` is simply because Intel decided not to support moving constant values into segment registers - there's no encodable instruction for it. instead, you must transfer the value via another register (in your code `ax` is used).

Your (original) description isn't quite right - the code does add the values at [3000:200] and [3000:202], but the result will be stored to [3000:204] (not [3000:202]).

Don't forget: the values stored in segment registers like DS (and CS, ES, FS and GS) do not specify a base address directly - they must always be multiplied by 16 to get the real base  address.

Answer (score 1):

Ds is the data segment register.  The address is as you mentioned made up from combining the ds register and si register.  In the old 8088/86 days, and perhaps still you computed your address (ds<<4)+si  in this case.  The mov to ax then ds is because there possibly do to a limitation of what you can/cant perform a move immediate.  maybe you cant do a mov ds,3000, in either case ax is used as an intermediate register for this, no connection at all just a way to get 3000 into the ds register.

So if ds = 3000 and si = 200 then the address is, I assume, (3000<<4)+200.

The connection between ds and si is implied.  Looking at a programmers reference manual from intel the DS segment is the default when SI or DI is used.  CS:ES:SS are alternates for SI (but not for DI), you would need to specify the alternate segment in the instruction/assembly to use one of the other segments.  How you specify that alternate segment depends on the syntax the assembler expects.

Answer (score 0):

In short words,

you cannot assign an immediate value directly to Segment Registers. Thats why you have that line using a General Register to do the job for you.

```asm
mov ds, ax
```

About DS and SI, you have some instruction that assume DS:SI to work properly, but this is not the case here. DS is your default data segment, so it is just assuming `DS:offset`; SI is your offset in your case. You can change SI to any other 16bit register, say, **CX** that it will work likewise. Make a test and feedback me :P